# how to return file descriptor in c

Tags: c, programming

I am confusing with this.

> > fp=fopen(filename,mode);

what is the value fopen() return to **fp**. is that value is file descriptor integer?

is fp  called as stream ? if not how to return a stream? when the streams are created?

how to return a file descriptor for a opened file using c?

is FILE stucture called inode table?

Comment: I think this question is well suited to stackoverflow.

Comment: It's more suited to S.O. than here, but you will still get chastised for clearly not having done **ANY** basic research to start with. There is no point in people regurgitating information that has surely been regurgitated online *tens of thousands of times*.  [Try this](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/input_and_output.html) -- if you can use the "find" feature in your browser (usually ctrl-f) you will notice `fopen` documented half way down.

Comment: `man fopen` works too.

Comment: There's even **[LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=C+fopen+example)** -- a great source of information.

Comment: This question as off-topic because it is about C programming and not *nix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fopen` is a library function, and it returns a `FILE` data structure. (Simplified) details about this structure may be found on [this page](http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-1587/2008/5/FILE-Structure.htm).

Among the members of this structure is a `char` called `fd`, labelled as the *file descriptor*. Every time a process opens a file using the `open` system call (which is what `fopen` does), an entry is created in a kernel internal table called the  *(global) file table*.

Another entry is then created in another, per-process table, called the *user file descriptor table*. This entry points to the previous one (in the kernel *file table*), and just like any entry in a table, it is given an index number. This index is what the process perceives as the *file descriptor*.

- File descriptor 0 is reserved for standard input.
- File descriptor 1 is reserved for standard output.
- File descriptor 2 is reserved for standard error output.

For this reason, when you call `open` for the first time in a program, you're very likely to get file descriptor 3. Then will come 4, and 5, and so on...

This file descriptor may then be used as a handle for every operation (system call) you want to perform on the file : `read`, `write`, `lseek` and `close` (which releases the file descriptor). You may refer to these system call's man pages for more information. It is also very common to find system calls used by a library function in this function's man mage. For instance, in `man fopen`, you'll see :

```
SEE ALSO
    open(2) ...
```

Now, the notions of *stream* and *inode* are a little different. The first one is purely conceptual in C : the data stream is what you make of it using the `read` and `write` system calls. The inode number, on the other hand, is associated to storage management more than it is to file access. On a file system, each file is associated to a data structure, stored in the filesystem's superblock. This data structure (called the inode) holds several pieces of metainformation about the file, such as :

- Access times
- Permissions (mode)
- Ownership
- Type (regular, directory, character, block, pipe, ...)
- Number of links (paths) to the file
- File size

This inode also allows the kernel to locate where the pieces of a file may be found on disk. For more information about this, I would recommend reading *The design on the UNIX operating system* by Maurice J.Bach (chapter 4, section 1, "Inodes"). You might also be interested in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).